# Change date format (12 hours) to elasticsearch time format (24 hours) with Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, timestamp

I'm working on an agent in `python` to send data to`elasticsearch` and I have a field that takes a date, and I need you not to read it as `string` but as time,

this is an example of the date I am getting `1/29/2019 3:59:06 PM` the date that I should get should have the following format`2019-01-29T03: 59: 06.142163-0500`

Thanks for all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `datetime` module, particularly `strptime` and `isoformat` methods.

For example:

```python
from datetime import datetime

your_time = '1/29/2019 3:59:06 PM'
result = datetime.strptime(your_time, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
print(result, type(result))
# 2019-01-29 15:59:06 <class 'datetime.datetime'>

new_time = result.isoformat(timespec='microseconds')
print(new_time, type(new_time))
# 2019-01-29T15:59:06.000000 <class 'str'>
```

You can learn more here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: i haved a problem with the timespec in python 3.4 (i need compatibility whit 2003 server), now i use new_time = result.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f-0500"), and now all is running